# Prototype extension

Tags: javascript, prototype

In my library, how do I extend prototype of Object thus the users of the library would be able to use that extension?

For example, inside my library I do `Object.prototype.greet = () => console.log("Hello")`. How do I make it possible for the end user of the library to use that method, just like `({}).greet()`?

Comment: You answered your own question... You already wrote the solution yourself!

Comment: I did this way, but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your code should work. Whats the problem

Comment: it says there is no such method

Comment: when I use in another module

Comment: [It works just fine](https://runkit.com/cherrydt/625eeaf1d10c8f0008440c1a), not sure what the problem is. Maybe you use it before it is defined?

Comment: Well, the question is not quite right: how do I make it accessible in other modules?

Comment: @Ergis: But `Object` should be the same for every module, no? (It would be a different thing across execution environments such as across IFrames or using the `vm` module.)

Comment: Here is the code, https://github.com/kerelape/monadic-objects/blob/develop/src/index.js

Comment: OK, the code is very different from what you showed in your question. You don't set `Object.prototype.xxx` but instead you attempt to write the whole `Object.prototype` (which is not writable)!

Comment: It's applaudable that you created a minimal example for your question, but next time please also verify that your example still exhibits the problematic behavior! (And if it doesn't, you just found the cause of your problem, and maybe you should then instead ask a question about why that thing caused it.) It can otherwise lead to a frustrating experience for both you and the people trying to help you, because you are posting code that works while claiming it doesn't, so there is no way to really go forward from that.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extending `Object.prototype` incorrectly. Actually, in your question you do it correctly, but in your actual code that you linked in a comment you do it wrong.

Your current code is this:

```js
Object.prototype = {
    ...Object.prototype,
    forEach: function(block) {
        return forEachEntryOf(this, block)
    },
    map: function(block) {
        return mapEachEntryOf(this, block)
    },
    filter: function(block) {
        return filterEachEntryOf(this, block)
    }
}
```

This cannot work, because you attempt to replace `Object.prototype` but that property is not writable! (Even if it were, it would mean that any objects created in the past would not have the new functionality, only new objects would, and additionally you'd destroy all kinds of default functionality because all the default methods in the prototype are non-enumerable and wouldn't even be copied over...)

The reason for why you don't recognize this problem is because you didn't enable strict mode. **I recommend to always use strict mode, to catch errors like these.**

With strict mode enabled (adding `'use strict'` at the top of the file), you get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'function Object() { [native code] }'

The solution is therefore to assign the individual properties or use `Object.assign`:

```js
Object.prototype.forEach = function (block) {
  return forEachEntryOf(this, block)
}

Object.prototype.map = function (block) {
  return mapEachEntryOf(this, block)
}

Object.prototype.filter = function (block) {
  return filterEachEntryOf(this, block)
}
```

...or...

```js
Object.assign(Object.prototype, {
  forEach: function(block) {
    return forEachEntryOf(this, block)
  },
  map: function(block) {
    return mapEachEntryOf(this, block)
  },
  filter: function(block) {
    return filterEachEntryOf(this, block)
  }
})
```

Comment: @kerelape Sorry, the `Object.assign` example was wrong - it was missing the `Object.prototype, ` part. Fixed.